# selenium Java get(index).sendKeys method can not be resolved

Tags: get, sendkeys

Wrote the following method to send keys into an element

```
public void enterDataIntoPickerWheel(String xpathSelector, String text,int index) {
    waitForElement(By.xpath(xpathSelector));
    driver.findElements(By.xpath(xpathSelector)).get(index).sendKeys(text);
}
```

It used to work perfectly fine, but not sure now the the code doesn't compile. 
I am using `Java 1.7` as my compiler.

My `java` and `mvn` versions:

```
Apache Maven 3.3.3 (7994120775791599e205a5524ec3e0dfe41d4a06; 2015-04-22T12:57:37+01:00)
Maven home: /Users/Bindu/Documents/Programs/apache-maven-3.3.3
Java version: 1.7.0_79, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.11.1", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Am I missing something here??

Comment: Hi I solved this issue so many times by changing the compiler version to 1.5 and above Check below post it might help you http://learn-automation.com/solution-for-sendkeyscharsequence-in-selenium/

Comment: Thanks @Mukeshotwani I found a work around for this. Changed the code to following and it works for fine. public void enterDataIntoPickerWheel(String xpathSelector, String text, int index) {
        waitForElement(By.xpath(xpathSelector));
        List<WebElement> wedriver.findElements(By.xpath(xpathSelector));
        we.get(index).sendKeys(text);
    }

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Mukeshotwani I found a work around for this. Changed the code to following and it works for fine. 
public void enterDataIntoPickerWheel(String xpathSelector, String text, int index) { waitForElement(By.xpath(xpathSelector)); 
List wedriver.findElements(By.xpath(xpathSelector)); we.get(index).sendKeys(text); }